# WCF web Service and getJSON returning empty data for cross-domain call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, wcf, rest

I have a WCF Service that return JSON format Data. When i use a Web Browser i can easily see the result but when using Jquery getJSON i cannot get it to work. i can see in fiddler that it is returning the data but in firebug it shows with red font and empty response.

here is my WCF service

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    UriTemplate = "GetUrl/{iType}")]
String GetUrl(string iType);



    public String GetUrl(string iType)
    {

            return strurl;
        }
```

MY JSON call looks like this

```
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/UrlSvc/UrlService.svc/GetUrl/1",
function (data) {
    console.log("Data JSOn Got");
    $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
        console.log("Data Received");
    });
});
```

when i just put that url in browser i get this below in response as expected

```
{"GetChartUrlResult":"ulr_fdba9bc2-7ff7-467f-a6e0-6f4d234169d2.png"}
```

BUT getJSOn returns Empty Response as seen in Firebug with Red font on the url Itself. 
this is a cross domain call and i have enabled cross domain it WCF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the call is cross domain, you have to use jsonp.  You can use it with `$.getJSON` by adding `?callback=?` to the URL (depending on the server-side API).  Make sure that your API does support emitting the callback appropriately.

Documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 3):

Browsers do not allow cross-domain AJAX calls and stop XMLHTTPRequest's from happening to any domain but the one that loaded the containing script or page.

To get around this, you can use JSONP calls that wrap the AJAX response in javascript.  You add the the following query string entry to your request:

```
callback=?
```

Also, note that if you are using WCF, you will need to enable JSONP in your service.  You do this by setting the crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled attribute to true in your to your config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  <standardEndpoints>
    <webScriptEndpoint>
      <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/>
    </webScriptEndpoint>
  </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

More information about JSONP and WCF can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834511.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be late to the party - you DO NOT have to use jsonp, i use WCF with angularjs, jquery, mobile apps, etc - and never use jsonp.

Just decorate your class and properties like the following and it will serialize.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyCustomClass
{
   [DataMemember]
   public string Name { get;  set;}
}
```